# Set thread local value in main thread and get in another thread

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, thread-local

i have been using [ThreadLocal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642243.aspx) for setting the value at one end and retrieve the value using get method at another end the code below is

```
public class sample()
{    
        public  ThreadLocal<Object> tl1 = new ThreadLocal<Object>();
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Myfunction));
            setname("myval");   
            thread.Start();
        }

        public void setname(String name)
        {
            tl1.Value = name;
        }
        public  String getname()
        {
            return (String)tl1.Value;
        }

        public void Myfunction()
        {
            String value=getname();
        }
}
```

i this i have set the value correctly in **setname method** ..

but whats its happening is when i try to get its value in separate thread the set value name is changed to null even though.

```
ex: "myval" changed to "null"
```

how can i solve this problem

Answer (score 5):

By definition, if you access it from another thread you will get an unrelated value - namely the value that is "local" to the second thread. It would be preferable to store the data in the context of what it relates to, rather than in the context of the thread - *especially* if this is actually something like ASP.NET (which does **not** guarantee to use the same thread for the entire duration of a request). For example, (going back to ASP.NET) the request has a context which allows storage of arbitrary key-value pairs.